# Kill a process at startup

Tags: startup, process, kill

So I switched to Gnome Shell on my 11.10 install. One annoyance is that whenever I insert a removable drive, nautilus opens the drive and at the same time gnome shell displays its popup. I discovered that killing the "gnome-fallback-mount-helper" process solves the issue. My question is: how can I kill the process at startup or better yet stop it from ever starting. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Run gnome-session-properties and either disable gnome-fallback-mount-helper or if that is not an option, add a custom command.

Answer (score 0):

In system configuration you can setup nautilus behaviour for every time you plug a removable drive. Look for it, I don't know the name in english; in spanish the app is called "Soportes extraíbles".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent nautilus from opening the drive automatically and just use gnome-shell's function for the media handling.
To do this open `gnome-control-center` from a terminal and search for '*Removable media*' option in the dialog. There are all available option for removable media (cd, dvd ... etc) in that window. 
For example to prevent nautilus from doing anything when a CD disk is inserted just choose the appropriate option "Do nothing"...

[image]

In the same way you can choose the option for various media types.